# How to add UI and toolbar to PDF.js viewer?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I'm trying to implement PDF.js on my project, but it's being harder than expected.

At the moment, I'm able to render a entire PDF inside a div, but I'm not able to render the standard toolbar viewer; you can see an example what I want at top of this demo page: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

My JS code looks like this at the moment:

```js
var url = '/filemanager/example.pdf';
var pdfScale = 1;
PDFJS.workerSrc = '/js/pdfJs/build/pdf.worker.js';

function renderPDF(url, canvasContainer, options) {
    var options = options || { scale: pdfScale };

    function renderPage(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport(options.scale);
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: ctx,
            viewport: viewport
        };

        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);

        page.render(renderContext);
    }

    function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
        for(var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++)
            pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(renderPage);
    }
    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
    PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);
}

renderPDF(url, document.getElementById('the-canvas'));
```

```html
<div id="the-canvas" class="text-center" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 450px"></div>
```

So... how can I the toolbar viewer with all controls like demo page?

Comment: have you tried applying this: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.js

Comment: No, how I can apply it? Can you post an example of code?

Comment: that was actually from https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Comment: @GabrielChiHongLee I know it, but I don't know how to use it in my project. Can you give me any suggestion?

Comment: @IsaacBosca you can just reference view.html with the file attribute being the location to your pdf, ie `http://www.example.com/viewer.html?file=http://www.example.com/file.pdf`per documentation here, https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-PDF.js-in-a-website

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately PDF.js package [maintainers have decided to remove viewer.html from their pre-built distribution NPM package](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/5609) because:

> There is a concern that end users mistake Firefox PDF Viewer with
> custom web site deployment, which will add support load to us.

You could copy this folder manually, but it would mean you would also need to update it manually, which is less than ideal approach for modern web application development.

While they have released reusable components for web developers, there is not much information on how to actually leverage these:

> We are slowly refactoring the viewer to provide set of embeddable
> APIs, so custom viewer can be easy deployed on a custom web site, also
> moving burden of the UI customization on web site developers. See
> web/pdf_viewer files and examples at
> https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/components and
> [#5552](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/5552)

All the examples, articles, and 3rd party packages (for my framework of choice) that I've come by are implementing their own UI features.

If someone has more examples on how to built upon PDF.js components, we are interested to read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the most simple approach:

- Download [PDF.js prebuilt](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download) files and place them in some directory of your project.
- Then create an iframe element, and pass the `src` attribute with the viewer source path (`/pdfjs-4.0.189-dist/web/viewer.html`), a path to the PDF file (`?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf`) and some of the defined parameters:

  `<iframe src="/pdfjs-4.0.189-dist/web/viewer.html?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf#page=2&zoom=200&pagemode=thumbs"></iframe>`

`file`: the PDF file path to use (must be on the same server due to JavaScript limitations). Must be encoded using encodeURIComponent, e.g. /viewer.html?file=%2Fpdf.js%2Fweb%2Fcompressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf

`page`: page number. Example: page=2

`zoom`: zoom level. Example: zoom=200 (accepted formats: [zoom],[left offset],[top offset], page-width, page-height, page-fit, auto)

`search`: search by text

`phrase`: search by phrase (accepted values: true, false)

`pagemode`: sidebar state. Example: pagemode=none (accepted values: none, thumbs, bookmarks, attachments)

[pdfjs-viewer-element](https://github.com/alekswebnet/pdfjs-viewer-element) package is a web component wrapper for PDF.js viewer and is based on this approach. [API showcase page](https://alekswebnet.github.io/pdfjs-viewer-element/#api) may be useful to visually test these parameters.
Additionally, using this package, you can select the viewer UI localization, set the viewer CSS theme (dark/light/auto) manually, or add your custom CSS.